# Pandas DataFrame initialized with a nested dict fail if only specify row index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I try to specify row index of a DataFrame initialized with a nexted dict.

```
pop={'Nevada': {2001: 2.4, 2002: 2.9}, 'Ohio': {2000: 1.5, 2001: 1.7, 2002: 3.6}}
pandas.DataFrame(pop, index=[2000,2001,2002])

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'astype'
```

However, if I also specify columns, it will work.

I am wondering if this is just a bug in Pandas. Because I am sure it definitely works on Python 3.5 and my older version pandas(NOT SURE earlier version).
I am running Python 3.6.5, Pandas 0.23.3.

This example is actually from Wes McKinney's book "Python for data analysis" (2nd Edition).

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem

Comment: I reproduced the problem with Python 3.5.5.

Answer (score 2):

I reproduced this problem in Python 3.7.1 with pandas 0.23.4.

The aim of this code section is used for clarifying that the order of index can be assigned artificially.

```
pd.DataFrame(pop, index = pd.Series([2001, 2000, 2002]))
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify the index as `pandas 0.23.0` will know the inner keys are indexes

```
pop={'Nevada': {2001: 2.4, 2002: 2.9}, 'Ohio': {2000: 1.5, 2001: 1.7, 2002: 3.6}}
df = pd.DataFrame(pop)

Nevada  Ohio
2000    NaN 1.5
2001    2.4 1.7
2002    2.9 3.6
```

Comment: The point is, I should be able to specify or select a subset of indices.